# MySQL data sort time in php

Tags: php

I am trying to sort  time in descending order . But problem is that  I am unable to sort time data .

```
<?php 
                      $date=date("Y-m-d");  
                    if (!empty($all_leads)):foreach ($all_leads as $v_leads){
                            //var_dump($v_leads);
                          $follow_date_call=   $this->items_model->max_date(array('leads_id' => $v_leads->leads_id), 'tbl_calls');
                          $follow_date_meet=   $this->items_model->max_date_meeting(array('leads_id' => $v_leads->leads_id), 'tbl_mettings');       

                          $c=strftime(config_item('date_format'), $follow_date_call->date);

                          $c_t=date('H:i', strftime($follow_date_call->date));
}
```

And Max_date function is here this is hold the my SQL  query

```
 public function max_date($where, $tbl_name)
    {    
         $this->db->select_max('date')->from($tbl_name);
         $this->db->where($where);
         $this->db->order_by($date, "asc");

         $query_result = $this->db->get();
         $result = $query_result->row();
         return $result;
    }
```

After print this date function return me out put like .
17:00 18:30 18:15.
and my requirement is like 17:00 18:15 18:30 this .
Any Help

Comment: You are not showing us all the code.  The 2 lines in your post would only give you just one time: 17:00, for example.  You must have these 2 lines inside a loop to get more than 1 time.  I assume your `print_r` is also inside that loop.  So you get things in the order from the database.  You need to save values in an array inside the loop.  Then, when the loop is done, call PHP's sort() function (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php )

Comment: Even better, have MySQL do the sorting for you.  What is the SQL statement you're sending to MySQL?

Comment: BareNakedCoder@ this is codiegniter based  project , I will ypdate my whole query

Comment: BareNakedCoder@you there ?

Comment: BareNakedCoder@I am trying with sort function even  I am trying php min () function  but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way is to push the unix time stamp in array and sort asc, Then you can extract the H:i(hour and minute) as below.

```
$date=date("Y-m-d");
        if (!empty($all_leads)):foreach ($all_leads as $v_leads){
            //var_dump($v_leads);
            $follow_date_call=   $this->items_model->max_date(array('leads_id' => $v_leads->leads_id), 'tbl_calls');
            $follow_date_meet=   $this->items_model->max_date_meeting(array('leads_id' => $v_leads->leads_id), 'tbl_mettings');

            $c[$follow_date_call->date]=date('H:i', strftime($follow_date_call->date));
        }
        ksort($c);

        //now you will have array ('unixtimestamp'=>'17:00', 'unixtimestamp'=>'18:15','unixtimestamp'=>'18:30')
        //with corresponding unix timestamp
```

let me know if this helps

Comment: Mirza@I am using this but not geting any out put

Comment: Mirza@you there my friend

Comment: @webquery yes i am here, are you getting the correct values of `$follow_date_call` & `$follow_date_meet`?? can you var_dump for me?

Comment: Mirza@ after var_dum getting this@@@@@@@object(stdClass)#153 (1) { ["date"]=> string(10) "1513958400" } object(stdClass)#146 (1) { ["date"]=> string(10) "1513963800" } object(stdClass)#384 (1) { ["date"]=> string(10) "1513962900" }

Comment: and when I am  do var_dump for this line, $c_t=date('H:i', strftime($follow_date_call->date));       @@then out is   17:00 18:30 18:15.

Comment: Mirza@mirja need your help

Comment: @webquery Please update your code to `$c[$follow_date_call->date]=date('H:i', strftime($follow_date_call->date));`  also updated in answer.

Comment: @webquery put `ksort($c)` outside the loop and to print after ksort statement var_dump($c);

Comment: can you use my team viewer for make change in my code . this is easy for you , i can share my teamviwer id

Comment: @webquery ok sure

Comment: Mirza@i can share my teamviwer ,your code is right  but i am unable to mange  this

Comment: @webquery send me your teamviewer details